# How to create new layer for Resnet?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I practice transfer learning by adapting and finetuning ResNet18 for CIFAR10. I want to replace the last fc layer with a new fc layer. So, I want to create a new layer but I didn't. How can I create a new layer?

Download Resnet18

```
OrigResNet18 = None
OrigResNet18 = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
```

Fast Layer

(fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1000, bias=True)

I tried but I am not sure this code:

```
num_in_features=OrigResNet18.fc.in_features
num_out_features=OrigResNet18.fc.out_features
NewResNet18.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=16, kernel_size= 
(3,3)) 
NewResNet18.fc=nn.Linear(in_features=num_in_features,out_features=num_out_features)
```

and I have error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-f8fe748d1e75> in <module>()
     32 NewResNet18 = NewResNet18.to(device)
     33 epochs = 1
---> 34 loss_history = train(NewResNet18, criterion, optimizer, epochs, trainloader)

6 frames
<ipython-input-57-a35bfc25b940> in train(model, criterion, optimizer, epochs, dataloader, verbose)
     19 
     20       # Obtain the scores
---> 21       outputs = model(inputs)
     22 
     23       # Calculate loss

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    247 
    248     def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 249         return self._forward_impl(x)
    250 
    251 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in _forward_impl(self, x)
    230     def _forward_impl(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    231         # See note [TorchScript super()]
--> 232         x = self.conv1(x)
    233         x = self.bn1(x)
    234         x = self.relu(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    397 
    398     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 399         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    400 
    401 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    394                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    395         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 396                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    397 
    398     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 1, 3, 3], expected input[8, 3, 224, 224] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

Comment: Usually if I want to make changes to an already existing architecture, I have to remake it from scratch. Making changes to an import comes with a lot of problems because of all the abstraction you aren't seeing. Resnet18 isn't too complex so hopefully it wont be too much of a problem if you decide to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this line:

```
NewResNet18.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=16, kernel_size= 
(3,3))
```

you are changing the first convolution to have 1 input channel (ie a grey-scale image), but you are feeding it a 3-channel image (ie an RGB image).

if you just want to change the size of the classifier, you can just use:

```
num_in_features=OrigResNet18.fc.in_features
num_out_features=OrigResNet18.fc.out_features
NewResNet18.fc=nn.Linear(in_features=num_in_features,out_features=num_out_features)
```